# Parametrising a straight line

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Question:**
>
> Parametrise
>
> $\Gamma_1=$ {$z\in \mathbb C:r\lt\lvert z \rvert\lt R, \arg(z)= \pi-\delta $}
>
> $\Gamma_2=$ {$z\in \mathbb C:r\lt\lvert z \rvert\lt R, \arg(z)= \delta - \pi $}
>
> As $\delta \rightarrow 0$

**My attempt:**

I am not quite sure how to parametrise it and then subsequently put it together. My attempt is $$r_1(t)= \pi(t)$$
$$r_2(t)= -\pi(t)$$

**Edit:**

After many grueling hours, I *might* have a working parametrisation

$$\Gamma_1^{*}(t)= t, \text{where} \ r \lt t \lt R$$
$$\Gamma_2(t)= -t, \text{where} \ r\lt t \lt R$$

Where $\Gamma_1^{*}(t) = -\Gamma_1(t)$

Is this the correct method?